# concatenate ruby parameter to object id, in haml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, string-concatenation

I work with ruby on rails.

this is part of my 'view' code **(file.haml**):

```
%div#all_ads
  - @ads.each_with_index do |ad,index|   
    %div#campaign_ads
```

I want to concatenate the index to the div id.

something like `%div#campaign_ads+index`

what have to be the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#all_ads
  - @ads.each_with_index do |ad, index|   
    %div{:id => "campaign_ads#{index}"}
```